# Typescript error on react useState hook when updating typescript version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state

I developed a react typescript application with react 16.9 and typescript 3.5.2.
It uses react state hooks like

```
const [hValue, setHValue] = useState();
```

type of the `hValue` is `IValue`

So the `setHValue` has return type `React.Dispatch<any>`

Then I updated the typescript version to 3.9.7 and it gives compilation errors and it seems that now the return type of `setHValue` has changed to `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<undefined>>`

Why is that? and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: what's the type of `hValue`?

Comment: `IValue` I edited the questions and included that

Answer (score 2):

Let's have a look at the type of `useState`

```
    function useState<S = undefined>(): [S | undefined, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S | undefined>>];
```

It is to say, if you didn't specify any `S`, it will be `undefined` by default.

So you will need to specify your initial type, say if `hValue` is a `number`, you can do

```
const [hValue, setHValue] = useState<number>();
```

In this way, `setValue` will be `React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>` type

Comment: In above example `setValue` will be `setHaValue: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number | undefined>>` type